# How to split tests into many files on go

Tags: go

I'm learning Go through writing a web app with the following structure

```
myapp/
  db/
    dbconf.yml
    migrations/
      *.sql
  handler
    modulea.go
    moduleb.go
  model
    init.go
    modulea.go
    moduleb.go
  myapp.go <-- this is my main package with main func
```

I added my some tests for the modulea in a file `myapp_test.go` on project root, I want to organize the tests by module but I dont know how-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place the tests for `modulea` in a file called `modulea_test.go` in the same folder and package as `modulea`.

Unit tests should be tested in the same package as the functions being tested.

Then to test it you can do `go test ./...` which will execute the tests for every package in your app.

Comment: So. it's better that each moduleX have its own folders model, handle, etc?

Comment: Think of packages as namespaces. They isolate code from other packages.  I'm assuming all your files under `model` folder belong to the `model` package. Same for `handler` folder will contain files that have `package handler`.

Comment: Finally I decide an approch `modulea/{handler,model,modulea_test}.go` thanks